# Domain redirects to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Tags: web-hosting, redirects

I have recently moved my domain to new hosting. Now when I try to access my site (`example.com`) it is being redirected to `http://example.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi`

If I use the domain name with a dot at the end, the website loads normally. I do not have any redirection configured, so what might be causing this?

Comment: I am not seeing this redirection. For me, your site loads OK (without a "dot at the end"). Have you tried clearing your cache? Tried different browsers etc? Are you still experiencing this problem?

Comment: Hi Chris, as @w3d the domain redirects fine and is most likely because your DNS either on your computer nic, computer software, route or isp has not yet updated, this is called DNS Propagation and varies from a couple of mins to over 24 hours depending on various things mentioned. If I've mistaken your problem then please feel free to leave a comment and I'll review it shortly.

Comment: You could try lowering the TTL as suggested in the linked question, or resetting your router, ensuring that your browser is not caching DNS, doing a IPconfig /flushdns etc.